# CSS Selectors Hover does not work

Tags: html, css

The styling does not change the display to block when hovering. I would appreciate any comments.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CSS Selectors</title>
    <style>
        div ul li:hover> ul {
            display:block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <ul>
            <li> List Item
                <ul style="display:none;">
                    <li> Child </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> List Item </li>
            <li> List Item </li>
            <li> List Item </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This might help http://css-tricks.com/hover-on-everything-but/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three reasons:

1. You cannot have a space in the pseudo selector.
2. Inline styles take precedence over embedded, so even if your selector is correct, the `display: block;` will have no effect.
3. You are selecting a ul which is a direct child of the div, whereas the ul that is set to not display is a child of the ul which is inside of the div, so that won't work.

Try something like this:

```
div ul ul {
    display: none;
}
div:hover ul ul {
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Or avoid !important and define that inner display:none like this `ul > li > ul { display:none}`

Comment: Thats a way better idea, I really should have done that to start with. Editing my answer, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Use !important for `display: block;`

Try

```
div ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block!important;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `!important` unless you **really** need to

Comment: Also your post tripped the low quality filter, probably because of its length.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to

```
div ul li:hover{
    display:block;
}
```